# Javascript update other input fields on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my input field after I changed to [kendo Numeric Text Box](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index). What this code need to do, is update two input fields, which are readonly.

Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    updatePrice();
    function updatePrice()
    {
        var playerInputCash = parseFloat($("#playerInputCash").val());
        var playerInputNumber = parseFloat($("#playerInputNumber").val());
        var percentage = (92/playerInputNumber);
        var total = (percentage*playerInputCash);
        var total = total.toFixed(0);
        
        var profit = (percentage*playerInputCash)-playerInputCash;
        var profit = profit.toFixed(0);
        $("#total").val(+ total);
        $("#profit").val(+ profit);
    }
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#playerInputCash", updatePrice);
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#playerInputNumber", updatePrice);
});
</script>

<input id="playerInputCash"/>
<input id="playerInputNumber"/>
<input id="total" readonly/>
<input id="profit" readonly/>
```

It was working fine before, but after the kendo it is not really working.
Figured out that the code works. The problem is the NumericTextBox, which is the input fields. I need to focus either total or profit in order to get them to update.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Anything in the console? I see a possible division by 0.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Seems to be working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b88pkLfp/

Comment: `[...]it is not really working[...]` is not really helpful, you need to tell what you expect should happen and what is happening instead. As `timgvandijk` already said, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Works fine. Also, do your `updatePrice();` AFTER you declare the function.

Comment: Figured out that it works. The problem is the NumericTextBox, which is the input fields. I need to focus either total or profit in order to get them to update.

Comment: @Snorlax this should only matter if the js engine is not standard compliant, because of the [hoisting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214724) in javascript.